# Oracle database performance issue

Tags: oracle

We are trying to pull data from an oracle database but seem to be getting very low performance.

We have a table of around 10M rows and we have an index via which we are pulling around 1.3k rows {select * from tab where indexed_field = 'value'} (in a simplified form).

SQuirreL reports the query taking "execution: 0.182s, building output: 28.921s". The returned data occupies something like 340kB (eg, when copied/pasted into a text file).

Sometimes the building output phase takes much longer (>5 minutes), particularly the first time a query is run. Repeating it seems to run much faster - eg the 29s value above. Is this likely to just be the result of a transient overload on the database, of might it be due to buffering the repeat data?

Is a second per 50 rows (13kB) a reasonable figure or is this unexpectedly large? (This is unlikely to be a network issue.)

Is it possible that the dbms if failing to leverage the fact that the data could be grouped physically (by having the physical order the same as the index order) and is doing a separate disk read per row, and if so how can it be persuaded to be more efficient?

There isn't much odd about the data - 22 columns per row, mostly defined as varchar2(250) though usually containing a few tens of chars. I'm not sure how big the ironware running Oracle is, but it lives in a datacentre so probably not too puny.

Any thoughts gratefully received.

Comment: Have you tried setting your fetch size larger, like 500 or so? I think for SQuirreL it's in something like File -> New Session properties -> General. 
And on a different troubleshooting note, what does the query speed look like if you don't select any columns? e.g. `select 1 from tab where indexed_field = 'value'`

Comment: Performance tuning is all about the details - data volumes and skew, distribution, indexes, statistics, etc. This question bis too woolly to be answerable.

Answer (score 1):

kfinity> Have you tried setting your fetch size larger, like 500 or so?

That's the one! Speeds it up by an order of magnitude. 1.3k rows in 2.5s, 9.5k rows in 19s. Thanks for that suggestion.

BTW, doing select 1 only provides a speedup of about 10%, which I guess suggests that disk access wasn't the bottleneck.

others>
The fetch plan is:

```
    Operation           Options                   Object        Mode        Cost    Bytes   Cardinality
0   SELECT STATEMENT                                            ALL_ROWS    6       17544   86
1   TABLE ACCESS        BY INDEX ROWID BATCHED    TAB           ANALYZED    6       17544   86
2   INDEX               RANGE SCAN                TAB_IDX       ANALYZED    3               86
```

which, with my limited understanding, looks OK.

The "sho parameter" things didn't work (SQL errors), apart from the select which gave:

```
Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production
PL/SQL Release 12.1.0.2.0 - Production
CORE    12.1.0.2.0  Production
TNS for Linux: Version 12.1.0.2.0 - Production
NLSRTL Version 12.1.0.2.0 - Production
```

I guess the only outstanding question is "what's the downside of setting the fetch size to a large value?". Given that we will always end up reading the entire result set (unless there is an exception) my guess would be "not much". Is that right?

Anyway, many thanks to those who responded and a big thanks for the solution.

Answer (score 0):

1.3k rows on a table of 10M rows for oracle is not too big.

The reason why second results are faster than first results is that oracle load data in RAM on the fisrt query and just read it from RAM on the second.

Are you sure that the index is well used ? Maybe you can do an explain plan and show us the result ?

Answer (score -1):

Few immediate actions to be taken are:

1. Rebuild the index on table.
2. Gather the stats on table.
3. execute following before rerun the query to extract execution plan.

   sql> set autotrace traceonly enable ;

turn this off by:

```
sql> set autotrace off ;
```

Also,provide result of following :

```
sql> sho parameter SGA 
sql> sho parameter cursor
sql> select banner from v$version;
```

- Abhi